# _WIN32_WINNT macro for both win7 and winxp

Tags: c++, windows

I am developing my code using VS2012 on Windows 7. It has to run on both Windows 7 and XP. Will my code run on **both** Windows 7 and XP if I set _WIN32_WINNT macro as follows:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601
```

?

Comment: No, it may not work on XP. You can use `0x0501` for XP and Win7 support.

Answer (score 3):

The _WIN32_WINNT definition is described here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sehtctf.aspx

It means that when you

```
#include <windows.h>
```

only function prototypes available in the version of windows numerically represented by _WIN32_WINNT are provided, and therefore statically linked.  As the compiler only references available functions in the OS for static linking the executable will work.

However, even if you don't modify _WIN32_WINNT as long as you only use functions from the target operating system the executable should work fine, but obviously you would want to test this rather than rely on your own knowledge of what functions are and are not available in each version of the OS.

If you try to use an executable which uses a function only provided by a later version of the OS, when you run your executable you will see a message box that says ""DLL import not found".

Comment: I appreciate that explanation, but my guess is that many of us looking for the answer know about that link.  The MS documentation doesn't clearly describe the effect of setting the macros.  The docs focus on how to set the macros which is great, but not on the meaning.  I've read that documentation several times and it is terribly written.  For instance, generally I don't need to know HOW to set a macro.  I need to know what each value really means, and what are the ramifications.

Comment: What I gather from these responses is that the earliest target OS needed is specified by the macros.  The target specified involves a trade off.  The earlier version that you target, the least amount of capability you get.  On the other hand, targeting a later version might cause problems if you need the app to run on an earlier version.  So bottom line is that if you have a requirement for the software to run on Windows 7 then you must target windows 7 or take the chance that something won't work right.  That is my interpretation which I couldn't ascertain from the MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting a version of Windows via `_WIN32_WINNT` then that code will use all the functions available to that platform. That means that if you target Windows 7, then certain Win7-and-above functions will be available to you, but these are not available on Windows XP. In general, your executable will run on Windows 7 and above, and not on Vista or XP. *

On the other hand, if you target Windows XP then you will be able to run the program on Windows 7 without issue, although you might miss out on some of the new features.

If you need one or two functions only available in Windows 7, then there are techniques such as dynamically loading the DLL and function entry points using `GetProcAddress` to be able to use new functions but still be able to run on XP.

---

*) It's not 100% sure what happens if you target Windows 7 and try to run on XP. As long as you restricted yourself to the subset of functions also in XP, and you happen to be lucky enough to not be using new flag values and no structures that have changed in size, then it will probably run, but of course there are no guarantees.